# Image is loading in ionic tabs from FileURI

Tags: ios, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

There is tab template in my mobile, same as instagram. When user clicks on camera, I have to collect FileURI and store in SQLite database with caption and date creation. When user clicks on saved feeds, loading all images from SQLite to saved tab view. But images are not loading.

ng-repeat = "post in posts"

post.thumb like file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F20EFD2B-E55D-4FF4-B2D4-AAF27BE25BF3/tmp/cdv_photo_029.jpg

I have Image URL and it [looks like](https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/280h/FSPLFPQBCZ.jpg.)

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?